# How to configure autorenaming suffix when file exist

Tags: configuration, downloads, rename

If you download a file ( to you're downloads folder , e.g) , and there's an existing file with the same name,  ubuntu renames the new file with a suffix like  original_name (2).extension

Is there any config option to remove the blank space and the parentesis ?

I'd like something more sneaky, like original_name_2.extension

thanks in advance

Comment: The downloading application does the renaming, not Ubuntu.

Comment: You would need to ask the creator of the software you use to download.